# how to redirect terminal output to multiple log files

Tags: io-redirection, tee, output

I've been trying redirect output to logfiles but should *NOT* be displayed on terminal, but following command does output both on terminal and in logs. Any ideas are appreciated.

`(some_cmd | tee -a log1 log2) 2>&1`

Comment: is `some_cmd` a standard utility?

Answer (score 9):

```
(some_cmd | tee -a log1 log2) 2>&1
```

That will pass stderr to stdout after tee, therefore it drops to your stdout in terminal.

Try to

```
some_cmd 2>&1 | tee -a log1 log2 >/dev/null
```

if you need to store stderr

and

```
some_cmd | tee -a log1 log2 >/dev/null 2>&1
```

in case you don't need stderr output.

Answer (score 0):

> some_cmd  | tee -a log1 | tee -a log2 | ... | tee -a logn  > /dev/null

Comment: Does it log errors to the log files?

Comment: If you do not want error log to be displayed on terminal, you can replace command as: `some_cmd 2> log_file`

Comment: no luck :-( it is still displaying output on the console

Comment: look like incomplete answer from me :(

Comment: @SHW Not necessarily, we do not know what "some_cmd" is, and some programs dump weird output

Comment: I'm building a sybase server using the following command 

`$SYBASE/$SYBASE_ASE/install/srvbuildres -r setup.rs`. 

i want to redirect output to log files, instead to be in terminal

Comment: You need to redirect `stderr` too. Possibly to `/dev/null`. @SHW: you were missing a `|` in your answer. And `tee` can take multiple files to write/append to. (though I'd never done that and wasn't sure till I saw Rush's answer) :)